# CSS3: Element positioning inside nav

Tags: html, css

I know that there are four different position values:

- static
- relative
- fixed
- absolute

What's really bothering me is the position of an element when i increase the marigin of it. Something like below.

> HTML

```
<header>
<h1>Welcome to Online Shopping System <button type="submit" onclick = "location.href = 'adminlogin.php';" id = "button" >Admin</button></h1>
</header>
<nav id = "navigation">
   <ul>
     <li><a href = "welcome.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href = "view.php">View</a></li>
     <li><a href = "login.php">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href = "signup.php">Signup</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: simple nav bar]

> Notice the grey background color effect that I have applied in the hover.

It clearly shows I'm messing up somewhere with the positioning, and it would be a plus if you could enlighten on **overflow** property too.

> CSS

```
header > h1
{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  text-indent: 65px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Garuda,sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li
{
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s; 

}

nav > ul > li > a 
{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: none;
  display: block;    
  line-height: .1em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 80%;
}

nav  li > ul li a 
{
  color: #111;
  display: block;  
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation
{
  background-color: brown;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 45px;
}

nav li:hover 
{
  background-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Four? What about `sticky`?

Comment: cool. does that help for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Probably not, just wanted to include that in the list.

Comment: i made a jsbin for you http://jsbin.com/pereqeriru/edit?output

Comment: @RachelGallen I downloaded and opened in firfox. It looks exactly the same as the picture I've posted except the background-color is "lightgrey" and the text is bold. However by changing the padding property inside my code from padding: 0.5em 0.5em; to padding: 0.5em 7em; I have somewhat resolved the issue but it still isn't as accurate as I wanted it to be.

Comment: @MuneerKhan i thought the picture was how you wanted it

Comment: @RachelGallen This is why I posted the code along with it. I have got that done and even further by changing the padding property as i mentioned. But I want the menu-bar list aligned in the center (without increasing the padding in between them)

Comment: why don't you center-align the text? like this http://jsbin.com/nanumivole

Comment: @RachelGallen Sorry for the late reply, had to catch a class. well technically, that will not help as I want to have a equal distance/space in between the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i got it, **I Think**, how You wanted?

[image]

**Remove** margin-left: 80%,

**Add** these into your CSS

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Does this helped?

Comment: This does exactly the same thing what changing padding: 0.5em 0.5em; to padding: 0.5em 7em; does. However I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to increase the "padding" which means the positions should be fixed.

Comment: @MuneerKhan if I understood, change justify-content: space-between and remove width 25%

Comment: I was going through old posts and found this helpful, so upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

this might help u a bit, sorry about my english.

**Overflow**:

```
 hidden:   hides everything what is not inside the area, no scrollbars.

 overlay:  shows scrollbars if needed and overlays scrollbars top of contents

 scroll:   show scrollbars normally

 visible:  shows all the child elements of current content, no area limitations.
```

Also you can set just overflow-x: hidden to prevent horizontal scrollbar for example and overflow-y: overlay to put scrollbar top of content.

**Position**:

```
fixed:     dependable window area, stays exactly where u point it
relative:  all child elements dependable to relative area
absolute:  dependable to a first upper relative area, scrolls with contents
static:    normal state
```

**Examples:**

```
<div style='position: relative; width: 100px; height: 20px;'>
    <!-- THIS GOES TO TOP OF WINDOW LEFT CORNER AND STAYS THERE -->
    <div style='position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;'></div>  

    <!-- THIS GOES TOP OF UPPER RELATIVE CONTENT RIGHT TOP CORNER -->
    <div style='position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;'></div>
</div>
<div style='position: relative; overflow: hidden'>
    <!-- THIS DIV YOU JUST NOT BASICALLY SEE, BECOUSE OF OVERFLOW HIDDEN -->
    <div style='position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;'></div>

</div>
```

I hope this helps You to understand it little better :)

Comment: I get that and I even tried using position: fixed; but sadly, that did'nt help either. sigh

Comment: Try text-align: left?

Comment: That will align the complete list to left with normal spaces in between but I want it to have enough spaces in between to cover the whole screen. One of the reason why I applied margin-left: 80%;